# can't read TXT in R with hash tag in the TXT file

Tags: r

```
data <- read.table(
  file = "Data/data_2021_03.txt",
  header = TRUE,
  sep = "\t",
  stringsAsFactors = TRUE
)
```

I have large TXT files that I try to read with R. Problem is that in the header a hash tag # is use. R sees this as a comment en stops reading the line after the '#'. But I get the error that I have more columns than headers. For one file I replace the '#' for a '*', in a txt editor. That works for one file. But I don't like to change my txt files. So how can I read a txt file with a '#' and replace it a '*' in R?

Comment: Add: `comment.char =  ""`

Answer (score 2):

Just set the comment character als empty string (see last line):

```
data <- read.table(
  file = "Data/data_2021_03.txt",
  header = TRUE,
  sep = "\t",
  stringsAsFactors = TRUE,
  comment.char=""
)
```